# Displaying a image from a URL in Android dialog

Tags: android, image, dialog

How would one go about displaying an image in the Android Dialog that is retrieved from the internet from a URL? I have seen examples of Dialogs with pictures (like here: http://quickandroid.blogspot.com/2011/03/alert-dialog-with-list-of-text-and.html) but all that I saw is how the piture is retrieved from the drawable folder.

How to display the image in a dialog from a URL? Is dialog even the best choice? Should I download the image first?

Thank you :)

Comment: You download the image via HTTP.  Then you create a Bitmap object by decoding the file.  Then you use an image view to display it.  The image view can be in a dialog if you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

you can use universal image loader to download image from web
see the link bellow

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 1):

Universal Image Loader is a good tip. No need to download the picture yourself. You can first download the picture with UIL, then inflate a `Dialog` from a layout (needs only contain an ImageView) and show the dialog. Or you can extend `DialogFragment`, download the picture and show it from there. 
If a dialog is the best way to show a picture is up to you and your app.